# How to speed up Api Controller Response using asynchronous code to run another task when a request is received?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

In my api controller, I have a method called "SendMail" that receives a post with a json body that looks like this:

```
{
    "MailTo": "abcdefg@hijklmn.opqrst",
    "Subject": "This is the subject",
    "Body": "This is the body"
}
```

When a request is received, the method "SendMail" validates the data and if it is correct, the mail is sent.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SendMail([FromBody] MailData mailData)
    {
        if(ValidateMailData(mailData) == true)
        {
             Email.send(mailData);
             return Ok("Your email was sent!");
        }

        return BadRequest("Some error");
    }
```

The problem is that the caller will only receive a response from the api when the mail is sent (and is taking to long), but I would like to only validate the data, return the response to the caller and then send the mail asynchronously (it's not important to the caller if the mail was actually sent or not, and if the data is validated correctly, it will be sent). This code is just an example, but illustrates precisely the problem that I am facing.

Comment: `async` doesn't mean "in parallel". The only real purpose of `async` is not to burn CPU while waiting for external resources (network, disk etc). Sending mail can be async in a way "I don't to burn my CPU while waiting for SMTP server to respond", but that doesn't matter in your task "queue email sending and return" - and that is, you need some kind of a queue here (background thread, thread pool, separate planner in database - whatever satisfy your needs / load etc).

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying. So basically i would instanciate a new thread

    Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Email.send(mailData)));

Start the process

    t1.Start();

And then return the response

    return Ok("Your email was sent!");

Comment: It can be a bit trickier in a way that ASP.Net in certain situations might abort child threads of a finished requests, so you might need to research "how to start thread in asp.net in a safe way", maybe consider using ThreadPool / Task / static Thread etc. It all depends on how important sending email per se, of course

Comment: Have you considered using [QueueBackgroundWorkerItem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/queuebackgroundworkitem-to-reliably-schedule-and-run-background-processes-in-asp-net/)?  It was designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decouple the web layer of your application from the actual service layer.
This is usually done by using queues.

The idea is that you have a web layer whose responsibility is getting user requests for some kind of work to be done, in your case the actual work is sending an email. The web service implementing the web layer of your app should expose an endpoint that a user can call in order to request that an email is sent. The web service endpoint should validate the content of the user request based on business rules that depends on your requirements.

If the user request is a valid one you will then enqueue the request in a dedicated queue and, then, you return a 202 accepted status code response (notice that you don't have to actually send the email before replying to the HTTP request, you just have to be sure that the user request has been successfully enqueued).

If, otherwise, the user request is not valid based on your validation rules you will return a 422 unprocessable entity status code, so that the user understands that its request is not valid.

The enqueued requests are, in the meantime, processed by one or more worker services which are separate applications (they are completely decoupled from the web server) whose responsibility is implementing the actual work to send the emails.

You can decide to use different technologies for the web server and the backend services, they just have to agree on the format of the messages enqueued by the web server and dequeued by the backend services. There are many ways to do so.

Notice that this kind of architecture is a bit more complicated than having just the web service, but it has many advantages. There is a clear separation of the concern and each piece of the infrastructure is able to scale well because it does only one thing and there isn't any shared resource contended by the different parts of your system (well, the queue is actually contended but there are very good technologies to help you implementing a queue the right way, like a service bus for example).

Another important thing to notice is that using async code in the web service layer **is not** a way to replying quicker to the single user, but instead is a technique useful to **better scale the web server itself**. Threads are important resources and are used by a web server to reply to incoming HTTP requests. When you perform IO tasks you should never block a thread letting it idle waiting for the IO task to complete. You should, instead, use an async api so that your thread starts the async task (for instance enqueuing a new request to send an email) and it is immediately returned to the thread pool, so that it can be used to reply to another incoming HTTP request (or doing other useful stuff) while the IO operation is being performed in the meantime by the operating system.

Think to this analogy (this was originally written by Jon Skeet). Imagine that you are at home and you want to eat a pizza. You decide to call your favourite restaurant and to order a pizza (in this analogy you are the thread and getting a pizza at home is the IO task).

Do you think is more efficient to order the pizza and then do other useful things while the pizza is traveling from the restaurant to your home, or sitting in front of the door waiting for the pizza and doing nothing in the meantime ? Well, if you are a web server you are very busy and for sure you have a lot of important things to do (read **service incoming HTTP requests**) while the pizza is traveling to your home.

Comment: I understood the idea of separating the web layer from the actual service layer, its the same principle of "a method should do one thing and be good at it. I am just not sure which "technologies" i need to use to implement such thing, but i guess i need to figured it out myself so i can learn. Anyways, thank you for opening my mind in this subject.

Comment: there are many choices to do so. In the .net world you can use asp.net core for the web layer, rabbitmq to implement a queue (use a library such as mass transit to do so, avoid using the raw rabbitmq api) and a .net core console application for the service layer